# Erro ao alterar modelo de aplicação C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Precisei alterar uma aplicação feita há algum tempo atrás em C# asp.net. Acrescentei a coluna no banco de dados que precisava e quando acrescento no model o campo correspondente, ao rodar a aplicação ela já não me identifica como usuário. (A aplicação usa windows authentication) 
E ao entrar em qualquer menu da aplicação, me retorna o seguinte erro:

**As informações de mapeamento e de metadados do EntityContainer 'Context' não correspondem mais às informações usadas para criar as exibições pré-geradas.**

O que eu preciso fazer para conseguir mexer na aplicação e acrescentar os novos campos que preciso ? Foi usado CodeFirst na criação da aplicação.

**EDIT**

Ao executar o comando Enable-Migration foi criada em minha aplicação uma pasta com o nome Migration com a seguinte configuração:

```
namespace GAWeb.WebApp.Migrations
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration</* TODO: put your Code     First context type name here */DbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

    }

        protected override void Seed(/* TODO: put your Code First context type name here */ )
   {


            ...

    }



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DataIntegration.Model.Entities;

namespace DataIntegration.Model.Repositories
{
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<IAccount> Accounts { get; }
    IRepository<IBudget> Budgets { get; }
    IRepository<IEmployee> Employees { get; }
    IRepository<IInvoice> Invoices { get; }
    IRepository<IItem> Items { get; }
    IRepository<IRequest> Requests { get; }
    IRepository<IRequestHistory> RequestsHistory { get; }
    IRepository<IRequestItem> RequestItems { get; }
    IRepository<IResultCenter> ResultCenters { get; }
    IRepository<IUnit> Units { get; }
    void Save();
    void Dispose(bool disposing);
}
}

namespace GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.Repositories
{
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private Context context = new Context();
    private GenericRepository<Employee> employees;
    private GenericRepository<Invoice> invoices;
    private GenericRepository<Voucher> items;
    private GenericRepository<Request> requests;
    private GenericRepository<RequestHistory> requestsHistory;
    private GenericRepository<RequestItem> requestItems;
    private GenericRepository<ResultCenter> resultCenters;
    private GenericRepository<Unit> units;

        public IRepository<Unit> Units
    {
        get
        {
            if (units == null)
                units = new GenericRepository<Unit>(context);
            return units;
        }
    }

    IRepository<IEmployee> IUnitOfWork.Employees { get { return Employees as IRepository<IEmployee>; } }

    IRepository<IInvoice> IUnitOfWork.Invoices { get { return Invoices as IRepository<IInvoice>; } }

    IRepository<IItem> IUnitOfWork.Items { get { return Items as IRepository<IItem>; } }

    IRepository<IRequest> IUnitOfWork.Requests { get { return Requests as IRepository<IRequest>; } }

    IRepository<IRequestHistory> IUnitOfWork.RequestsHistory { get { return RequestsHistory as IRepository<IRequestHistory>; } }

    IRepository<IRequestItem> IUnitOfWork.RequestItems { get { return RequestItems as IRepository<IRequestItem>; } }

    IRepository<IResultCenter> IUnitOfWork.ResultCenters { get { return ResultCenters as IRepository<IResultCenter>; } }

    IRepository<IUnit> IUnitOfWork.Units { get { return Units as IRepository<IUnit>; } }
```

Essa é a Entitites que eu quero alterar:

```
using System;

namespace DataIntegration.Model.Entities
{
public interface IRequestItem : IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    DateTime Data_Retorno { get; set; } // Esse é um campo que quero acrescentar a aplicação e ao banco
    int Quantity { get; set; }

    string Employee_Id { get; set; }
    IEmployee Employee { get; set; }
    string Unit_Id { get; set; }
    IUnit Unit { get; set; }
    string ResultCenter_Id { get; set; }
    IResultCenter ResultCenter { get; set; }
    int TaxiRequest_Id { get; set; }
    IRequest Request { get; set; }
}
```

}

Classe Context

```
public class Context : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public Context()
        : base(DatabaseInfo.CONNECTION_STRING)
    {
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    public bool Validate<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        return ValidateEntity(Entry(entity), null).IsValid;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //TABLE MAPS
        modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>().ToTable(DatabaseInfo.UNITS_TABLE);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ResultCenter>().ToTable(DatabaseInfo.CENTERS_TABLE);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable(DatabaseInfo.EMPLOYEES_TABLE);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Request>().ToTable(DatabaseInfo.TAXI_REQUEST_TABLE);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Voucher>().ToTable(DatabaseInfo.VOUCHERS_TABLE);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RequestItem>().ToTable(DatabaseInfo.REQUEST_ITEM_TABLE);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().ToTable(DatabaseInfo.TAXI_INVOICE_TABLE);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RequestHistory>().ToTable(DatabaseInfo.REQUEST_HISTORY_TABLE);


  }

    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
}
```

Generic Repository

```
namespace GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.Repositories
{
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    private Context context;
    private DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual bool IsValid(TEntity entity)
    {
        return context.Validate(entity);
    }


    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
         Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
         Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        params string[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }


    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetLoadedByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Local.Single(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }


    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Context.Views

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     O código foi gerado por uma ferramenta.
//     Versão de Tempo de Execução:4.0.30319.544
//
//     As alterações ao arquivo poderão causar comportamento incorreto e serão perdidas  se
//     o código for gerado novamente.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly:  System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewGenerationAttribute(typeof(Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews.ViewsForBaseEntitySets7F3AFE99A19115C1600A2D3407EFC3D1F36FBA78AF0470677E19E4A993E04F7B))]

namespace Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews
{


/// <Summary>
/// O tipo contém exibições para EntitySets e AssociationSets que foram gerados em tempo de design.
/// </Summary>
public sealed class ViewsForBaseEntitySets7F3AFE99A19115C1600A2D3407EFC3D1F36FBA78AF0470677E19E4A993E04F7B : System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewContainer
{

    /// <Summary>
    /// O construtor armazena as exibições para as extensões e também os valores de hash gerados com base nos metadados e no fechamento e nas exibições do mapeamento.
    /// </Summary>
    public ViewsForBaseEntitySets7F3AFE99A19115C1600A2D3407EFC3D1F36FBA78AF0470677E19E4A993E04F7B()
    {
        this.EdmEntityContainerName = "Context";
        this.StoreEntityContainerName = "CodeFirstDatabase";
        this.HashOverMappingClosure = "edf2b152bf40e88b95f3411ab7b29fa2627c7224d571c8d9557eef38c0f29386";
        this.HashOverAllExtentViews = "10a3551ac384c60e8d31d44333d96794897a405b3f595947069bdd8f21e80060";
        this.ViewCount = 16;
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// O método retorna a exibição do índice fornecido.
    /// </Summary>
    protected override System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetViewAt(int index)
    {
        if ((index == 0))
        {
            return GetView0();
        }
        if ((index == 1))
        {
            return GetView1();
        }
        if ((index == 2))
        {
            return GetView2();
        }
        if ((index == 3))
        {
            return GetView3();
        }
        if ((index == 4))
        {
            return GetView4();
        }
        if ((index == 5))
        {
            return GetView5();
        }
        if ((index == 6))
        {
            return GetView6();
        }
        if ((index == 7))
        {
            return GetView7();
        }
        if ((index == 8))
        {
            return GetView8();
        }
        if ((index == 9))
        {
            return GetView9();
        }
        if ((index == 10))
        {
            return GetView10();
        }
        if ((index == 11))
        {
            return GetView11();
        }
        if ((index == 12))
        {
            return GetView12();
        }
        if ((index == 13))
        {
            return GetView13();
        }
        if ((index == 14))
        {
            return GetView14();
        }
        if ((index == 15))
        {
            return GetView15();
        }
        throw new System.IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para CodeFirstDatabase.Invoice
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView0()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("CodeFirstDatabase.Invoice", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Invoice
    [CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Invoice](T1.Invoice_Id, T1.Invoice_Code, T1.Invoice_Date, T1.Invoice_Value, T1.Invoice_Discount)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Invoice_Id, 
        T.Code AS Invoice_Code, 
        T.Date AS Invoice_Date, 
        T.[Value] AS Invoice_Value, 
        T.Discount AS Invoice_Discount, 
        True AS _from0
    FROM Context.Invoices AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para CodeFirstDatabase.Voucher
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView1()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("CodeFirstDatabase.Voucher", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Voucher
    [CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Voucher](T1.Voucher_Id, T1.Voucher_Code, T1.Voucher_Purpose, T1.Voucher_Date, T1.Voucher_Value, T1.Voucher_AdjustedValue, T1.Voucher_Status, T1.Voucher_Note, T1.[Voucher.Employee_Id], T1.[Voucher.Request_Id], T1.[Voucher.Unit_Id], T1.[Voucher.ResultCenter_Id], T1.[Voucher.Invoice_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Voucher_Id, 
        T.Code AS Voucher_Code, 
        T.Purpose AS Voucher_Purpose, 
        T.Date AS Voucher_Date, 
        T.[Value] AS Voucher_Value, 
        T.AdjustedValue AS Voucher_AdjustedValue, 
        T.Status AS Voucher_Status, 
        T.Note AS Voucher_Note, 
        T.Employee_Id AS [Voucher.Employee_Id], 
        T.Request_Id AS [Voucher.Request_Id], 
        T.Unit_Id AS [Voucher.Unit_Id], 
        T.ResultCenter_Id AS [Voucher.ResultCenter_Id], 
        T.Invoice_Id AS [Voucher.Invoice_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM Context.Vouchers AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para CodeFirstDatabase.Employee
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView2()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("CodeFirstDatabase.Employee", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Employee
    [CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Employee](T1.Employee_Id, T1.Employee_Name, T1.Employee_Active)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Employee_Id, 
        T.Name AS Employee_Name, 
        T.Active AS Employee_Active, 
        True AS _from0
    FROM Context.Employees AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para CodeFirstDatabase.Request
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView3()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("CodeFirstDatabase.Request", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Request
    [CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Request](T1.Request_Id, T1.Request_Date, T1.Request_Justification, T1.Request_Note, T1.Request_Processed, T1.[Request.Employee_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Request_Id, 
        T.Date AS Request_Date, 
        T.Justification AS Request_Justification, 
        T.Note AS Request_Note, 
        T.Processed AS Request_Processed, 
        T.Employee_Id AS [Request.Employee_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM Context.Requests AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para CodeFirstDatabase.RequestHistory
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView4()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("CodeFirstDatabase.RequestHistory", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing RequestHistory
    [CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.RequestHistory](T1.RequestHistory_Id, T1.RequestHistory_Date, T1.[RequestHistory.Request_Id], T1.[RequestHistory.Item_Id], T1.[RequestHistory.Employee_Id], T1.[RequestHistory.Unit_Id], T1.[RequestHistory.ResultCenter_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS RequestHistory_Id, 
        T.Date AS RequestHistory_Date, 
        T.Request_Id AS [RequestHistory.Request_Id], 
        T.Item_Id AS [RequestHistory.Item_Id], 
        T.Employee_Id AS [RequestHistory.Employee_Id], 
        T.Unit_Id AS [RequestHistory.Unit_Id], 
        T.ResultCenter_Id AS [RequestHistory.ResultCenter_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM Context.RequestHistories AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para CodeFirstDatabase.Unit
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView5()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("CodeFirstDatabase.Unit", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Unit
    [CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Unit](T1.Unit_Id, T1.Unit_Code, T1.Unit_Name, T1.Unit_Manager, T1.Unit_Description, T1.Unit_Year, T1.Unit_Level, T1.Unit_Type, T1.[Unit.Parent_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Unit_Id, 
        T.Code AS Unit_Code, 
        T.Name AS Unit_Name, 
        T.Manager AS Unit_Manager, 
        T.Description AS Unit_Description, 
        T.Year AS Unit_Year, 
        T.Level AS Unit_Level, 
        T.Type AS Unit_Type, 
        T.Parent_Id AS [Unit.Parent_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM Context.Units AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para CodeFirstDatabase.ResultCenter
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView6()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("CodeFirstDatabase.ResultCenter", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing ResultCenter
    [CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.ResultCenter](T1.ResultCenter_Id, T1.ResultCenter_Code, T1.ResultCenter_Name, T1.ResultCenter_Description, T1.ResultCenter_Year, T1.ResultCenter_Level, T1.ResultCenter_Type, T1.ResultCenter_Usage, T1.ResultCenter_StartDate, T1.ResultCenter_ExpirationDate, T1.ResultCenter_Active, T1.[ResultCenter.Parent_Id], T1.[ResultCenter.Unit_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS ResultCenter_Id, 
        T.Code AS ResultCenter_Code, 
        T.Name AS ResultCenter_Name, 
        T.Description AS ResultCenter_Description, 
        T.Year AS ResultCenter_Year, 
        T.Level AS ResultCenter_Level, 
        T.Type AS ResultCenter_Type, 
        T.Usage AS ResultCenter_Usage, 
        T.StartDate AS ResultCenter_StartDate, 
        T.ExpirationDate AS ResultCenter_ExpirationDate, 
        T.Active AS ResultCenter_Active, 
        T.Parent_Id AS [ResultCenter.Parent_Id], 
        T.Unit_Id AS [ResultCenter.Unit_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM Context.ResultCenters AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para CodeFirstDatabase.RequestItem
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView7()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("CodeFirstDatabase.RequestItem", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing RequestItem
    [CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.RequestItem](T1.RequestItem_Id, T1.RequestItem_Date, T1.RequestItem_Data_Retorno, T1.RequestItem_Quantity, T1.[RequestItem.Employee_Id], T1.[RequestItem.Unit_Id], T1.[RequestItem.ResultCenter_Id], T1.[RequestItem.TaxiRequest_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS RequestItem_Id, 
        T.Date AS RequestItem_Date, 
        T.Data_Retorno AS RequestItem_Data_Retorno,
        T.Quantity AS RequestItem_Quantity, 
        T.Employee_Id AS [RequestItem.Employee_Id], 
        T.Unit_Id AS [RequestItem.Unit_Id], 
        T.ResultCenter_Id AS [RequestItem.ResultCenter_Id], 
        T.TaxiRequest_Id AS [RequestItem.TaxiRequest_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM Context.RequestItems AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para Context.Invoices
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView8()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("Context.Invoices", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Invoices
    [GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.DAL.Invoice](T1.Invoice_Id, T1.Invoice_Code, T1.Invoice_Date, T1.Invoice_Value, T1.Invoice_Discount)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Invoice_Id, 
        T.Code AS Invoice_Code, 
        T.Date AS Invoice_Date, 
        T.[Value] AS Invoice_Value, 
        T.Discount AS Invoice_Discount, 
        True AS _from0
    FROM CodeFirstDatabase.Invoice AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para Context.Vouchers
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView9()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("Context.Vouchers", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Vouchers
    [GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.DAL.Voucher](T1.Voucher_Id, T1.Voucher_Code, T1.Voucher_Purpose, T1.Voucher_Date, T1.Voucher_Value, T1.Voucher_AdjustedValue, T1.Voucher_Status, T1.Voucher_Note, T1.[Voucher.Employee_Id], T1.[Voucher.Request_Id], T1.[Voucher.Unit_Id], T1.[Voucher.ResultCenter_Id], T1.[Voucher.Invoice_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Voucher_Id, 
        T.Code AS Voucher_Code, 
        T.Purpose AS Voucher_Purpose, 
        T.Date AS Voucher_Date, 
        T.[Value] AS Voucher_Value, 
        T.AdjustedValue AS Voucher_AdjustedValue, 
        T.Status AS Voucher_Status, 
        T.Note AS Voucher_Note, 
        T.Employee_Id AS [Voucher.Employee_Id], 
        T.Request_Id AS [Voucher.Request_Id], 
        T.Unit_Id AS [Voucher.Unit_Id], 
        T.ResultCenter_Id AS [Voucher.ResultCenter_Id], 
        T.Invoice_Id AS [Voucher.Invoice_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM CodeFirstDatabase.Voucher AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para Context.Employees
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView10()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("Context.Employees", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Employees
    [GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.DAL.Employee](T1.Employee_Id, T1.Employee_Name, T1.Employee_Active)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Employee_Id, 
        T.Name AS Employee_Name, 
        T.Active AS Employee_Active, 
        True AS _from0
    FROM CodeFirstDatabase.Employee AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para Context.Requests
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView11()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("Context.Requests", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Requests
    [GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.DAL.Request](T1.Request_Id, T1.Request_Date, T1.Request_Justification, T1.Request_Note, T1.Request_Processed, T1.[Request.Employee_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Request_Id, 
        T.Date AS Request_Date, 
        T.Justification AS Request_Justification, 
        T.Note AS Request_Note, 
        T.Processed AS Request_Processed, 
        T.Employee_Id AS [Request.Employee_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM CodeFirstDatabase.Request AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para Context.RequestHistories
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView12()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("Context.RequestHistories", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing RequestHistories
    [GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.DAL.RequestHistory](T1.RequestHistory_Id, T1.RequestHistory_Date, T1.[RequestHistory.Request_Id], T1.[RequestHistory.Item_Id], T1.[RequestHistory.Employee_Id], T1.[RequestHistory.Unit_Id], T1.[RequestHistory.ResultCenter_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS RequestHistory_Id, 
        T.Date AS RequestHistory_Date, 
        T.Request_Id AS [RequestHistory.Request_Id], 
        T.Item_Id AS [RequestHistory.Item_Id], 
        T.Employee_Id AS [RequestHistory.Employee_Id], 
        T.Unit_Id AS [RequestHistory.Unit_Id], 
        T.ResultCenter_Id AS [RequestHistory.ResultCenter_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM CodeFirstDatabase.RequestHistory AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para Context.Units
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView13()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("Context.Units", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing Units
    [GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.DAL.Unit](T1.Unit_Id, T1.Unit_Code, T1.Unit_Name, T1.Unit_Manager, T1.Unit_Description, T1.Unit_Year, T1.Unit_Level, T1.Unit_Type, T1.[Unit.Parent_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS Unit_Id, 
        T.Code AS Unit_Code, 
        T.Name AS Unit_Name, 
        T.Manager AS Unit_Manager, 
        T.Description AS Unit_Description, 
        T.Year AS Unit_Year, 
        T.Level AS Unit_Level, 
        T.Type AS Unit_Type, 
        T.Parent_Id AS [Unit.Parent_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM CodeFirstDatabase.Unit AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para Context.ResultCenters
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView14()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("Context.ResultCenters", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing ResultCenters
    [GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.DAL.ResultCenter](T1.ResultCenter_Id, T1.ResultCenter_Code, T1.ResultCenter_Name, T1.ResultCenter_Description, T1.ResultCenter_Year, T1.ResultCenter_Level, T1.ResultCenter_Type, T1.ResultCenter_Usage, T1.ResultCenter_StartDate, T1.ResultCenter_ExpirationDate, T1.ResultCenter_Active, T1.[ResultCenter.Parent_Id], T1.[ResultCenter.Unit_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS ResultCenter_Id, 
        T.Code AS ResultCenter_Code, 
        T.Name AS ResultCenter_Name, 
        T.Description AS ResultCenter_Description, 
        T.Year AS ResultCenter_Year, 
        T.Level AS ResultCenter_Level, 
        T.Type AS ResultCenter_Type, 
        T.Usage AS ResultCenter_Usage, 
        T.StartDate AS ResultCenter_StartDate, 
        T.ExpirationDate AS ResultCenter_ExpirationDate, 
        T.Active AS ResultCenter_Active, 
        T.Parent_Id AS [ResultCenter.Parent_Id], 
        T.Unit_Id AS [ResultCenter.Unit_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM CodeFirstDatabase.ResultCenter AS T
) AS T1");
    }

    /// <Summary>
    /// exibição de retorno para Context.RequestItems
    /// </Summary>
    private System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> GetView15()
    {
        return new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>("Context.RequestItems", @"
SELECT VALUE -- Constructing RequestItems
    [GAWeb.VoucherRequests.Model.DAL.RequestItem](T1.RequestItem_Id, T1.RequestItem_Date, T1.RequestItem_Data_Retorno,T1.RequestItem_Quantity, T1.[RequestItem.Employee_Id], T1.[RequestItem.Unit_Id], T1.[RequestItem.ResultCenter_Id], T1.[RequestItem.TaxiRequest_Id])
FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Id AS RequestItem_Id, 
        T.Date AS RequestItem_Date, 
        T.Data_Retorno AS RequestItem_Data_Retorno,
        T.Quantity AS RequestItem_Quantity, 
        T.Employee_Id AS [RequestItem.Employee_Id], 
        T.Unit_Id AS [RequestItem.Unit_Id], 
        T.ResultCenter_Id AS [RequestItem.ResultCenter_Id], 
        T.TaxiRequest_Id AS [RequestItem.TaxiRequest_Id], 
        True AS _from0
    FROM CodeFirstDatabase.RequestItem AS T
) AS T1");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Faltou você dizer como essa `UnitOfWork` é instanciada e como as `IEntities` são preenchidas.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Pronto

Comment: Preciso também do código da classe `Context`. Pode por favor colocar na pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: Só existe este DbSet? `public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }`. Estou atualizando a resposta.

Comment: Sim, adicionei a pergunta a outra classe que tem referência a dbSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é *Code First*, está errado você alterar o banco manualmente.

O que é correto fazer é:

1. Adicionar a coluna diretamente no *Model*;
2. Gerar uma *Migration* através do *Package Manager Console*: Dentro do seu Visual Studio, vá em <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>:

   ```
   Add-Migration MinhaMigrationDeAtualizacao
   ```
3. Atualizar o banco após ter gerado a *Migration* no *Package Manager Console*:

   ```
   Update-Database
   ```

Se o projeto utiliza migrações automáticas, o passo 2 é opcional.

Para conferir se seu projeto utiliza migrações automáticas, veja o construtor da classe `Configuration` no seu arquivo `Migrations\Configuration.cs`, que deve ser mais ou menos assim:

```
namespace GAWeb.WebApp.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    // coloque aqui um using para o namespace onde está sua classe Context.

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Context context)
        {
              /* This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

              You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
              to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.

                context.People.AddOrUpdate(
                  p => p.FullName,
                  new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
                  new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
                  new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
                ); */

        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Essa resposta exigiu esmiuçar muito a aplicação, então algumas providências podem ser tomadas para se ganhar tempo.

- Verifique se o contexto possui um arquivo `Views` acoplado a ele. Essa é uma abordagem antiga do Entity Framework, que não é mais usada desde a versão 4. Este arquivo deve ser removido para funcionar corretamente a abordagem por `Migrations`.
- Verifique se seu projeto faz ou não uso de arquivos EDMX. Se usar, possivelmente esse arquivo tem que ser destrinchado em arquivos de `Model`. [Este link explica como fazer isso](http://nullablecode.com/2013/09/splitting-entity-framework-model-classes-separate-projects/).

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54190/discussion-on-answer-by-cigano-morrison-mendez-erro-ao-alterar-modelo-de-aplicac)